# UnauthorizedAccessException when initializing SpeechSynthesizer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, speech-to-text, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm using Microsofts SpeechSynthesizer to create audio output for my Windows Phone app. I use this code

```
private async void TextToSpeech_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    await synth.SpeakTextAsync("You have a meeting with Peter in 15 minutes.");
}
```

I get this exception:

```
{System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.

at Windows.Phone.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer..ctor()
at NerdQuiz.Question.<TextToSpeech_Tap>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)}
```

I found out that the error occurs at

```
new SpeechSynthesizer();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have added the capability `ID_CAP_SPEECH_RECOGNITION` to the application manifest (WMAppManifest.xml).

Comment: Thanks. I thought I only needed it for recognizing, but not for synthesizing. Once again I learned something...

Comment: How? My capabilities section has entries like `<Capability Name="internetClientServer" />` and `<DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />` so I'm not sure how to add `ID_CAP_SPEECH_RECOGNITION`

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Universal Apps (UWP apps), Using the **SpeechSynthetizer requires the Microphone capability**.
(I don't know why, but once enabled I didn't get the exception anymore)