# UnauthorizedAccessException when using speech synthesis on WinRT device?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, text-to-speech

I have a C# Windows Store App that gets a System.UnauthorizedAccessException whenever I try to use speech synthesis:

```
       SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await this._tts.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Hello ragdoll man!");

        // Send the stream to the media object.
        this._mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
        this._mediaElement.Play();
```

The Exception occurs on the first line when I call SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync().  It's not a package manifest *capabilities* issue like some people have on Windows Phone 8:

[UnauthorizedAccessException when initializing SpeechSynthesizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344253/unauthorizedaccessexception-when-initializing-speechsynthesizer)

I say this because first, Windows Store App manifests do not have a ID_CAP_SPEECH_RECOGNITION capability and second, as a test I **checked every available capability box** on the *Capabilities* tab and I still get the exception.

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me in a new empty Windows 8.1 app project:

```
private async void UIElement_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // The media object for controlling and playing audio.
    MediaElement mediaElement = this.media;

    // The object for controlling the speech synthesis engine (voice).
    var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    // Generate the audio stream from plain text.
    SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Hello World");

    // Send the stream to the media object.
    mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
    mediaElement.Play();
}
```

Comment: I saw that sample code on MSDN and tried it originally and "media" was not defined for the "this" object, which in my case is a Page object.  What is the "this" object in your solution?

Comment: Oh, it's a `Page`. I just added a `MediaElement` to the page.

Comment: And you called it "media"?  If so, there is no functional difference between your code and mine.