# Adding speech synthesis and recognition to a Windows Phone 8.1 universal app's application manifest

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

When using speech recognition in a Windows Phone app you have to remember to add the speech recognition capability `ID_CAP_SPEECH_RECOGNITION` to the app's application manifest, as advised in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19345332/575530) or the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207021(v=vs.105).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206936(v=vs.105).aspx)

In Windows Phone 8 these settings would, I believe, have been available through the Capabilities page of Manifest Designer, as we can see from this screenshot taken from the ['How to modify the app manifest file for Windows Phone 8' documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj247542(v=vs.105).aspx):

[image: VS2012 Windows Phone 8 Capabilities]

But in Windows Phone 8.1 under Visual Studio 2013 the Capabilities page of the Manifest Designer does not look like that. It looks like this:

[image: VS2013 Windows Phone 8.1 Capabilities]

There is no entry for speech recognition there. So I assume I need to edit the `Package.appxmanifest` file in the project directory. The relevant section looks like this:

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
  </Capabilities>
```

How would I add `ID_CAP_SPEECH_RECOGNITION` to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ID_CAP_SPEECH_RECOGNITION` is a red herring for getting speech recognition and synthesis working using `Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition` and `Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis` on Windows Phone 8.1. As Kunal Chowdhury points out in his blog post [Windows Phone 8.1 Text-To-Speech - What’s changed for #WPDev](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2014/06/whats-new-for-wp8dev-text2speech.html) we just need to enable the Microphone capability which, as we can see in the screenshot in the question, is available in the Capabilities page of the Manifest Designer under Visual Studio 2013.